# <div style="height:100%"> is bigger than page because of upper-menu's height. How to fix this?

Tags: css, html, height

Specifially, this code:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#FFDDDD">head</div>
        <div style="height:100%; background-color:#DDFFDD">body</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is rendered bigger than the window, creating a permanent scrollbar:

[image: rendered site]

What is a proper way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are making this div 100% height:

```
<div style="height:100%; background-color:#DDFFDD">body</div>
```

the height property in % will make the div take up that percentage of its container, which in this case is the HTML `<body>`, so changing the header div to be `height: 10%` and the body div to be `height: 90%` should fix the problem.

Comment: With results that vary based on window size.

Comment: Adding `overflow-y: hidden` to the body div will get rid of the permanent scroll bar issue.

Comment: @AlexW this is actually the best answer to my particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it this way:

HTML

```
<div class="header"> Header</div>
<div class="main">Main content area</div>​
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: yellow;
}

.header {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/EDWTM/

Comment: But I need the body-div properly taking the remaining of the page for vertical-align:center purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Move the background color to the body, and lose the height.

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color:#DDFFDD">
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#FFDDDD">head</div>
        <div>body</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4XVrW/

Alternatively, you could use margins and absolute positioning to place the header above the body:

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0px">
        <div style="height: 30px; width:100%; background-color:#FFDDDD; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;">head</div>
        <div style="height:100%; background-color:#DDFFDD;">body</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I need the body-div properly taking the remaining of the page for vertical-align:center purposes.

Comment: I wonder what other details you left out of your question.  I can only recall two solutions I've used for this: javascript to resize the second div, and http://giveupandusetables.com/